# Hourglass over Qt Creator breakpoint, program not breaking

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have created a very simple Qt Creator console application, with defaults for everything except for the `main.cpp` file, which I have edited as follows:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "world" << std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have also added two breakpoints; one for each of the `std::cout` lines, by left-clicking on the margin to the left of the line number. This creates a red circle in the margin, with a small purple hourglass over the circle. When I build and run the application, the output is:

```
hello
world
```

and the program does not break at these lines in the IDE. Why not?

Comment: Which version are you using? Which platform, which debugger, etc, is it? Just in case, have you tried disabling all the optimizations should you have any? Have you tried eliminating the QCA usage altogether if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to click on "Start Debugging" (F5) instead of click on "Run" (Ctrl + R)?

Answer (score 0):

@Trilarion: Antonio Borondo's question is justified. It appears as if the author of the original question actually hit the Run button (or pressed Ctrl-R, or ...) instead of hitting the Debug button (or F5, or ...). Getting a clarification on what he did is important to answer the original question.

As you noticed, commenting is not available to everybody, so asking in an "answer" is the only way forward.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else still has this issue, this is most likely caused by the build not being set to **Debug**.

In Qt Creator 4.5.x, you can set the build type in the lower left hand corner, you will see an icon of a monitor, when you click on it, you will have a choice of **Debug**, **Profile**, or **Release**. When you set the build to **Debug**, you will no longer have hourglass icons on your breakpoints, and the program will break on these lines.